# Transforming sorting into Dijkstra single source path?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dijkstra, shortest-path

To get a lower bound of nlogn I am taking the sorting algorithm, which is well known to have that, and transforming/adapting it to Dijkstra's single source shortest path problem.

I know you need to do create a graph based on the numeric values and that Dijkstra will traverse it in order, any help with the rest and how to evaluate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about making a [star graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) (a graph with a single central node and a bunch of "outer ring" nodes, where each outer ring node has one edge connecting it to the central node) with n outer ring nodes. Then, link up each node v<sub>i</sub> in the outer ring to the central node by an edge whose cost is the ith entry of the array. If you then run Dijkstra's algorithm starting at the central node, the algorithm will visit each of the outer ring nodes in ascending order of distance, corresponding to listing the array elements in sorted order.

Hope this helps!